# CSS3 text editor software

Tags: html, css, wysiwyg

I'm looking for a software similar to Photoshop, but to create a CSS3 styled text. I want to be able to create a styled text using WYSIWYG editor and then automatically generate HTML5+CSS3 code. Is there any software like this?

Comment: like this: http://css3generator.com/?

Comment: Yes, exactly, but only for text. There are many different effects I can achieve with CSS3: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/css3-text-effects-typography/ . I'm wondering if there is a software or an online tool to apply different effects to a text and then automatically generate CSS3 code.

Comment: @Thomas. Yes, or like Photoshop. Let's say I add a text, apply different effects, shadows, gradients and then export it as a working CSS3 code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out, most effects will work on text, also lokks just like photoshop layers styles:

http://layerstyles.org/builder.html

Comment: This is very close. Thanks Alex!